# BOOST ASIO: Server crash when sending on closed connection

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Boost version 1.43

Platform: WindowsXP

I have this boost TCP server which crashes (throws boost exception somewhere ) only when the client suddenly closes the connection when I send him data (i.e. in the middle of the `"asio::send(..)"`):

Here is the server code around the crash. It fails to catch the exception (probably because it is thrown in a different thread)

```
try
{
    boost::asio::write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(*buffer));
}
catch(boost::system::system_error &e)
{
    const char* err_str = e.what();
    std::cout << "ECXEPTION NEVER CAUGHT! " << err_str << std::endl;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should post more code, there's nothing obviously wrong with what you have postd so far. What is the exception that is thrown? Is it thrown from a thread invoking `io_service::run()`?

Comment: Yes. Probably.. This happens only when the client suddenly dies or closes the connection is some unclean way

Comment: did you see my other two questions from the previous comment?